Please make the links in "Related" and "Hot Network Questions" only touchable when clicked on the text
In the "Related" questions and "Hot Network Questions" under a question post even if you accidentally click on the white background you will go to that question page.
Please change it so that the links are only clickable on the text itself (for example, by underlining the link text, just like the links in the question body).


Technically, it means making them plain links and not menu items.

@ShadowWizard Maybe there's a way to help resolving the issue while they remain menu items?

Not really, menu items by their definition should be clickable as whole. Guess one can come with a userscript and/or custom CSS to do what you want, sadly I don't have time for that.
